# Understanding wildcards when specifying test assemblies for the MSTest runner in TeamCity 7

Tags: teamcity, mstest

Basically I want to specify "all files that end with Test.dll", also known as `*.Test.dll`. `*.Test.dll` doesn't work, presumably because it matches only files in the current working directory.

However, I didn't have any luck with `**\*Test.dll` either. For some reason I had to use `**\bin\**\*Test.dll` for it to find any test assemblies it could run.

The TeamCity 7 documentation for MSTest doesn't say anything about wildcards, as far as I can tell. Can someone help me understand wildcards when specifying test assemblies for the MSTest runner in TeamCity 7?

Is it possible to specify files matching a certain file name pattern, but in whatever directory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the TeamCity documention on [Wildcards](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Wildcards) `**\*Test.dll` should have worked. So either it's a bug or the forward slash versus backward slash issue is significant.

Comment: I reported it as a bug to Jetbrains: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24220

Comment: Actually including `bin\debug` in the path along with *backward* slashes worked.

Comment: It is a bug confirmed in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24220 however that was marked as done and its not. I re-opened the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-45533.

Comment: Had the same issue with NUnit 3, and this fixed things for me. It is 2018!