# Teamcity NUnit Tests - No assemblies found

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

I am trying to get TeamCity set up for a project. I want to run a scheduled build that includes a step where NUnit Tests are run.

My NUnit build step looks like this:

```
Runtime: NUnit-2.6.3 v4.0 MSIL
Run tests on: **/Tests/*.dll
Execute: If all previous steps finished successfully
```

But every time I run the build I get an error saying:

`No assemblies were found.`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Also, conceptually, this build step will happen BEFORE the project is actually built. But how will there be any Test DLLs (assemblies) unless the project is built in the first place?

Comment: Have you verified on your build agent that those directories actually exist and have files? And no, you can't run the tests before they have been built? Why have you set it up like that?

Comment: The agent is local. And yes, the DLLs do exist in the used directory.

Comment: Just to make sure, add a command line build step before the test step and add this command: `dir /s`, then run this and see what the build log says. Do you see your test dll's there?

Comment: Done. Shows all the directories that my solution has. I can see the "Tests" directory.

Comment: And there are dll's in there?

Comment: Yes, plenty of DLLs in its subdirectories. (Although this brings me back to the doubt I had - if NUnit step is before build, then how can there be any DLLs without a build?)

Comment: They're most likely leftovers from a previous build. Unless you've activated the feature on your build configuration to clean the build directories (SWABRA), then a build directory from a previous build might be reused. Again, *why* are you trying to run your tests before the code has been built? (I don't know why it doesn't do it though)

Comment: I have not enabled the CLEAN BUILD option. And I don't know of another way to run my NUnit Tests through TeamCity. Is there?

Comment: How do you know that the tests will be run before the build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56656/discussion-between-lasse-v-karlsen-and-ritratt).

Comment: I suspect this may be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084822/understanding-wildcards-when-specifying-test-assemblies-for-the-mstest-runner-in/13085277#13085277

Comment: Oh I checked again and apparently there are no DLLs in the Tests subdirectory!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest that you build your projects before running tests. Most common way to achieve this is that you have separate configurations for building code and running tests.

Your build configuration would generate artefacts (containing assemblies most likely).

Test run configuration would extract this artefact package, via artefacts dependency, then in build step you run tests from specific assembly.

This is the most common approach and using this approach you do not have to worry about files in the files system. Teamcity's snapshot isolation and artefacts dependencies will take care of this (when properly configured)

If you need an example how to achieve this, let me know.

Comment: This worked. I had forgotten to include a separate step for building the project (MSBuild, VS sln build etc.)

Comment: @Dejan can you provide an example or a link with such an example of what you described in your answer? I think that's exactly what I need but I am quite new to teamcity and not sure how to do various configurations.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't have this problem when I first set it up and when I did it threw me off for a while. But yes, the tests depend on other projects being built first. +1

Comment: Maybe it was pure luck, if you have VCS Triggers set up on both (build and test) configruations maybe the build configuration trigger was triggered before test, hence, tests had artefacts ready