# Teamcity only running first MSTest - ignores the rest

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, teamcity

I would to run Visual Studio 2019 tests in Teamcity. I have configured a step as per the screenshot below. Teamcity runs the test dll under the "Test file names" setting but only the first one and ignores the second one. It does not matter what order I put the dll paths in, it always only runs the first one only. I also tried adding a comma at the end of a dll. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: are you sure you use newline char to break that lines and that the path are the relative path from the project. I would try to use wildcards (*) in the name. That works for me.

Comment: I've tried them and still nothing. I also pick the files using the file selector icon beside the text box.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this one
[Understanding wildcards when specifying test assemblies for the MSTest runner in TeamCity 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084822/understanding-wildcards-when-specifying-test-assemblies-for-the-mstest-runner-in)

I guess

```
**\bin\*\*\*Test.dll
**\*\bin\*\*Test.dll
```

should work for you.